# How can I disable old TLS versions in exim?

Tags: exim, gnutls

I'm running an [Exim](https://www.exim.org/) MTA which only receives emails from a few other systems under my control. All these systems happily negotiate TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3 with my MTA. I would like to disable support for TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 but I can't find instructions on how to do so.

All software is installed from the official Debian 10 repository (Exim 4.92, GnuTLS 3.6.6).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to this file `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` somewhere like in the TLS section (or as described [here](https://www.transip.eu/knowledgebase/entry/5389-disabling-tls-and-your-mailserver/#disabling_tls_1_0_and_1_1_in_exim)):

```
tls_require_ciphers = SECURE192:!VERS-SSL3.0:!VERS-TLS1.0:!VERS-TLS1.1:!VERS-DTLS0.9:!VERS-DTLS1.0
```

- Restart/reload exim with `sudo systemctl restart exim4`.
- Verify the exim settings updated with `sudo exim -bP | grep tls_require_ciphers`.

For further reading on tls_require_ciphers see [here](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html#SECTreqciphgnu).

Answer (score 2):

[GnuTLS options in Exim](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html#SECTreqciphgnu)

See the bit about using `tls_require_ciphers` and the GnuTLS priority string definitions. The example which pertains to you is:

```
tls_require_ciphers = NORMAL:%LATEST_RECORD_VERSION:-VERS-SSL3.0
```

... which you could further tweak to suit your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line like this to the config file.  Edit it for your required and unrequired ciphers.

```
# We need to disable SSL2 and key lengths < 128 bits for PCI compliance
tls_require_ciphers = ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+SHA:!MD5:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXP:!DES
```

Comment: Note that I would like to disable old _protocol_ versions which is an orthogonal problem to disabling ciphers.

Comment: "to the config file", which one? Exim is the absolute worst in documenting where config should go, I've been reading for a full hour in their docs, but it's still unclear.

Comment: "It Depends". The config file on Debian installations is autogenerated by default and usually lives in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template. It may live in /etc/exim4/conf.d/ if you split the config up into smaller files. On other GNU/Linux installs I have no idea where it's installed unfortunately.